# Elasticsearch: how can I search documents with distinct, sorting, pagination, filtering

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I make in ES something like this in SQL?

```
SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, field3 FROM table_name 
WHERE field1 = "value1" AND field3 = "value3"
ORDER BY field1 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

I tried many bucket aggregations, but could not meet all the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start like this:

```
POST table_name/_search
{
  "from": 10,
  "size": 10,
  "_source": false,
  "sort": {
    "field1": "asc"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field1": "value1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "field3": "value3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "field1",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "hits",
      "size": 1,
      "_source": [
        "field1",
        "field2",
        "field3"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to start with this but couldn't find a way to add distinct. After that, I moved on to trying to implement with aggregation. So far, the options with composite and significant terms aggregations have been the closest to a solution.

Comment: I didn't add any aggregation because there was no GROUP BY clause in your query. See my updated query which leverages [field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html).

Comment: The collapsing is only done on `field1`. You can definitely remove the constraint on `field3` from the `bool/filter` query and that will work as you expect.